# How can a Steam turbine be recovered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-factorization

I just broke my Factorization Steam Turbine by mining it with a diamond drill, what is the right tool for that job? I am on Tekkit-Lite.

Comment: Do you mean breaking it so you can pick it back up.

Answer (score -2):

You need an obsidian drill. I can't remember how to make it right now, but use Not Enough Items to figure it out!